# How to solve the Schrodinger Equation on a sphere with a step potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, coordinate-systems, schroedinger-equation

I am currently trying to solve the Schrodinger equation on a sphere that is subjected to an axially symmetric step potential given by:
$$
V(\theta)=\begin{cases}
0~~~~~~~~\text{if }~~ \theta_{min} < \theta < \pi - \theta_{\min} \\
V_0~~~~~~\text{if }~~\theta < \theta_{\min} ~~\text{or } \theta> \pi - \theta_{\min}
\end{cases}
$$

The phi dependence of this equation is the same as normal, and I have so far numerically solved the theta dependence by approximating the hamiltonian as a finite dimensional tridiagonal matrix of size $n \times n$ where we have $n$ theta steps. This has worked so far, but I am now trying to solve the equation analytically.

The issue lies with the theta dependence, as it reduces to Legendre's equation. In the regions of the sphere containing the poles, the equation is:

$$
(1-z^2)\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\Theta-2z\frac{d}{dz}\Theta+\left [2(E-V_0)-\frac{m^2}{1-z^2} \right]\Theta = 0
$$
Where $z=\cos(\theta)$.

Seeing as the only bounded solutions to the Legendre equation on the interval containing $z = -1$ are those where the degree is an integer, I had assumed that this would restrict the quantity $2(E-V_0)$ to be of the form $\lambda(\lambda +1)$, where $\lambda$ is an integer. This would mean that the energies are restricted to $E = \frac{\lambda(\lambda +1)}{2}+V_0$, differing from the normal spherical harmonics by only an added factor of $V_0$. But this does not agree with what my numerical solution has yielded, nor does it seem qualitatively correct as I do not think I can stitch together a continuous and differentiable function when I connect it to the solution on the middle portion of the sphere.

What am I missing here? Are there other analytical methods I can try to solve the solution with?

Comment: The angular dependence is general and requires only spherical symmetry. You are essentially trying to reinvent spherical harmonics, you can check out the relevant [wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics) to get unstuck.